# How do I disable the 'click' event on each day from "Date Range Picker"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, click, daterangepicker

I'm trying to prevent the 'click' event on each day of the [DateRangePicker](http://www.daterangepicker.com/), I'm just trying to prevent users from changing the date range.

I created a 'pen' on Codepen, this is the link: https://codepen.io/jnts/pen/yQPwmB

**HTML**

```
<input data-start="16/11/2018" data-end="16/12/2018" type="text" name="dates">
```

**Javascript**

```
const self = $('input[name="dates"]')

self.daterangepicker({
    applyButtonClasses: 'd-none',
    showDropdowns: false,
    opens: "center",
    drops: "down",
    autoApply: false,
    startDate: self.data('start'),
    endDate: self.data('end'),
    minDate: self.data('start'),
    maxDate: self.data('end'),
    locale: {
      format: "DD/MM/YYYY",
      separator: " - ",
      firstDay: 1
    }
});
```

I've already tried to add the "disabled" attribute on the `input`, but this only prevent the 'click' event on the `input`, so the DateRangePicker does not appear.

I just wanna show the date range on a 'Read Only' kind of way.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `pointer-events: none` to an element with CSS will prevent any click events firing from that element. To disable click events on the open calendar, add the following to your stylesheet:

```
.drp-calendar {
 pointer-events: none;
}
```

See forked code here: https://codepen.io/sungaila/pen/rQJOMQ